# ORM Inheritance

Tags: inheritance, orm

Has anyone *really* wanted and used inheritance support on ORM tools, and if yes which one do you think offers the best support?

Or is ORM Inheritance a "pie in the sky" concept?

Comment: what do you mean by ORM inheritance?

Comment: Being able to have entity classes deriving from other entity classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like this question a lot. I've used ORM tools (Toplink, now eclipselink, Hibernate) for a while and I've always seen this as referenced in JPA documents but I've never really had a need for it. Basically my philosophy is the ORM is just there to prevent you from writing tedius code to pull out records for the database. That really is the huge timesaver and it prevents you from making stupid mistakes. Sure you can do fancy stuff with this, but why not save it for the controller (if you're following MVC) than stick it in the model?

Comment: So would you say the traditional "one class per table" approach works for most cases?

Comment: In my case that's what I've always found. Using inheritance there just confuses the mapping IMO and is more of a toy than anything useful.

Answer (score 7):

I have used inheritance with Hibernate (and some with Django), and regreted it dearly.

The "composition over inheritance" principle is especially true for domain classes. While I agree that there is a few cases where inheritance makes sense at the model level, in most cases inheritance will give you a very static domain model, where one object will not be able to change to another class.

I also find that most developers are not comfortable with the concept of inheritance at the database level, so maintenance becomes more complicated.

And last, there are some technical problems, like proxies put in place by Hibernate that will hide the actuall class of an object. It makes "instance of" behave stangely. Of course, you might say that "instance of" is a code smell and that maybe it is another hint that composition is probably a better solution ...

Comment: Looks like a straight class-per-table (with composition) is the way to go from what I'm reading here. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: don't agree. If you keep in mind that you can't change an entity from one class to another, this is a very powerful technique as it lets you apply your common OOP knowledge to an otherwise relational model.

Comment: As for checking the actual type behind a proxy, it's VERY smelly... use a visitor or polymorphism: http://www.hibernate.org/280.html

Comment: well composition over inheritance is common OOP knowledge too, of course, but sometimes inheritance is more convenient (oh no, I hear a flame war coming! ;-) ) Anyway, it's another tool you can (or not) use.

Comment: @mausch - If you were to use an ORM tool, would you consider inheritance "indispensable to have" or just "nice to have"?

Comment: It's certainly not indispensable, but *very* nice to have. It enables you to do polymorphic queries, see this example: http://metaarchit.com/hibernate_tutorials/Hibernate%20Tutorial%2008.pdf

Comment: I would agree that it is a nice to have, but you have to be carefull not to over use it.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean inheritance in the domain classes, I use it all the time with NHibernate and/or Castle ActiveRecord, they support the three mapping strategies:

- http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/#inheritance
- http://old.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/usersguide/typehierarchy.html

Comment: Thank you, I'll check them out.

Comment: @Mauricio I am working on a project that has a type of record we will call `Master`. There are about 17 types of Master records, most have similar data fields but each might have one or two unique fields. The people before me used inheritance to make a Master entity class with 17 entity subclasses.  That seemed great at first, but after working with it for awhile I am wondering if one `Master` table that allowed null values might not have been better (e.g. there are 17 different tables now in the database, I can't change one type to another easily). I would really appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: @mattblang Hi Matt, don't confuse inheritance in the domain classes with mapping strategy. You could have 17 subclasses mapped to individual tables or to a single table, check the NHibernate docs for reference. If you need to change one type to another, you already noticed that inheritance in general, and table-per-class in particular, do not work well.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing complex business software, you need it.

Let's say you want to be able to sell stuff to individuals or organizations. On a sales order, the buyer would be one or the other. How do you do that without inheritance?

With inheritance, you'd do something like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
public abstract class Party {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  ...
}

@Entity
public class Individual extends Party {
  ...
}

@Entity
public class Organization extends Party {
  ...
}

@Entity
public class SalesOrder {

  private Party buyer;

  ...
}
```

Then you can do:

`salesOrder.setBuyer(someOrganization)` or `salesOrder.setBuyer(someIndividual)`