# How do I integrate inheritance technique when writing the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, entity-relationship

I am trying to use inheritance for sake of re-usability and I have a base class named 'Partner' and two sub classes 'Lawyer' and 'Accountant' as below:

```
abstract class Partner{

}

class Lawyer extends Partner{

}

class Accountant extends Partner{

}
```

It's all good with the code, but I was wondering more when it comes to database, how do I store these information in db, should I have one table partners for both entities, or I should have separate tables for each entity, based on fact that these two differs from each other based on their attributes.
If I keep it in separated tables, and I have another table 'cases' which is related to partner:
cases: case_id, subject, description,partner_id.... My question is, how do I inner join entities based on user logged in, let say if he is laywer join lawyer table or vice versa, what if I keep adding more entities in future?

How would I do it in such a way that eventhou in future I add more Entities my db queries will not have to be changed again and again.

Comment: This question (which doesn't use PHP, but your code looks java-y): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594961/orm-inheritance seems like it could help point you in the right direction. The key term is "ORM" - Object Relational Mapping.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I have asked regarding the db... nothing is relevant what u have commented to my question. and I dont think eithr ORM has to do anything here!

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I favor the idea of combining lawyers and acct's into one table partners.  My suggestion is to keep your db entities separate. So you will have three tables (lawyer, accountant, and cases) and cases will contain foreign keys from lawyer and accountant. Your inner joins will be simple in this case. You'll have two 1:1 relationships whereas using a partner table it will have to be 1:M relationship to get both the lawyer and the accountant - each being its own record within the Partners table. Plus don't forget all the useless NULLS you'll have since lawyers and accountants have their own specific attributes..eew!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are going to use Lawyers and Accountants in the same context, I think it makes sense to use the same table.

You can simply create a `partners` table with the common properties, and create separate `accountants` and `lawyers` tables with a 1:1 relationship. This basically means these two tables don't get their own auto-incrementing primary key, but just a `partner_id` that is primary and refers to the `id` in the partner table.